# javascript: how to sort divs by contents of children

Tags: javascript, sorting

saw some similar questions but they were for jquery or unanswered. Was wondering if it's possible, or even worth it, to sort divs by the innerHTML of their children in vanilla js. Maybe it's something I should leave to a plugin like [list js](https://listjs.com/).

I was hoping to sort the rendered elements, I don't want to rewrite all the divs as json objects, if possible.

Here's a template I set up of what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/ssccdd/9Lo2xy0s/4/

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const  desc = false;
  const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("item"); 
  let arr=[];
  for(let i=0; i< divs.length; i++){
    arr.push(divs[i].getAttribute('data-ticker'));
  }
  console.log(arr)

  sortName = () => {
    console.log('sorting by name');
  }

  sortNumber = () => {
    console.log('sorting by number');
  }

  sortPrice = () => {
    console.log('sorting by price');
  }

  trimChars = (word) => {
    return parseFloat(word.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
  }
  
  document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("click", sortName);  
  document.getElementById("number").addEventListener("click", sortNumber);  
  document.getElementById("price").addEventListener("click", sortPrice); 
}
```

```css
.item{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 4px solid cornflowerblue;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
Sort by 
<button id="Name">name</button>
<button id="Number">number</button>
<button id="Price">price</button>

<div id="container">
  
  <div class="item" data-ticker="AAR">
    <div class="name">Asparagus salad</div>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="price">$10</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" data-ticker="BUT">
    <div class="name">Bacon sandwich</div>
    <div class="number">6</div>
    <div class="price">$3.23</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" data-ticker="CAT">
    <div class="name">Carrot cake</div>
    <div class="number">9</div>
    <div class="price">$4.12</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" data-ticker="WHA">
    <div class="name">Whiskey</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
    <div class="price">$12</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

this way:

```js
const
    containerRef = document.querySelector('#container')
  , items = [...containerRef.querySelectorAll('div.item')]
              .map(item=>
                ({ name  : item.querySelector('.name').textContent
                , number : Number(item.querySelector('.number').textContent)
                , price  : parseFloat(item.querySelector('.price').textContent.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''))
                , itmRef : item
                }))

document.getElementById('Name').onclick = () =>
  {
  items.sort((a,b)=>a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
        .forEach(el=>containerRef.appendChild(el.itmRef) )
  } 
document.getElementById('Number').onclick = () =>
  {
  items.sort((a,b)=>a.number - b.number)
        .forEach(el=>containerRef.appendChild(el.itmRef) )
  } 
document.getElementById('Price').onclick = () =>
  {
  items.sort((a,b)=>a.price - b.price)
        .forEach(el=>containerRef.appendChild(el.itmRef) )
  }
```

```css
.item{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 4px solid cornflowerblue;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
Sort by 
<button id="Name">name</button>
<button id="Number">number</button>
<button id="Price">price</button>

<div id="container">
  
  <div class="item" data-ticker="AAR">
    <div class="name">Asparagus salad</div>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="price">$10</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" data-ticker="BUT">
    <div class="name">Bacon sandwich</div>
    <div class="number">6</div>
    <div class="price">$3.23</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" data-ticker="CAT">
    <div class="name">Carrot cake</div>
    <div class="number">9</div>
    <div class="price">$4.12</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" data-ticker="WHA">
    <div class="name">Whiskey</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
    <div class="price">$12</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks mr jojo, appreciate it, but I'm specifically looking for a div solution not tables, have seen that there are table solutions out there.

Comment: @StephD No, this is not table solution. its look like Table but it is Divs

Comment: @StephD Did you try my answer once I put your html and css back in it?